# what's better way to share connection pool between inside RequestHandler and outside RequestHandler in tornado

Tags: python, global-variables, tornado

What's the better way to share a connection_pool in both Application/Handler and other place outside Handler like a test file, or a model file?

in `main.py`, I define a db_pool in Application, I could use it in any RequestHandler, what if I want to use it outside RequestHandler?

What's the better practice?

code in `main.py`

```
import tornado.web
class Application(tornado.web.Application):

    """
        自定义的Application
    """

    def __init__(self):
        # I have a db_pool here
        init_dict = {
            'db_pool': PooledDB.PooledDB(MySQLdb, **db_server)
        }

        super(Application, self).__init__(
            [(r'/', IndexHandler, init_dict)],
            **settings)
```

code in `test.py`

```
from main import Application
# I want to get db_pool here
```

code in `dao.py`

```
def get_config(user):
    # I want to get db_pool in main
    db = db_pool.connection()
    return
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I would store the connection pool inside the `Application` class, instead of passing it to your `Handlers`. Then, you could access the application inside your handler by calling `self.application` inside your GET/POST methods.

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = PooledDB.PooledDB(MySQLdb, **db_server)
        super(Application, self).__init__([(r'/', IndexHandler)], **settings)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):            
        self.application.db.<put a valid method here>()
```

Comment: actually I want to use `db` outside RequestHandler base classes, not in `get`/`post`